# интересная задача на select на подумать

Tags: sql, sql-server

Всем добрый день!

Не соображу как подступиться к задаче.

Есть таблица data c полями report_date (отчетная дата), inn (работодатель), client_id (сотрудник), для упрощения будем считать, что report_date принимает 2 значения - 01.01.2018 и 01.12.2017 .

Нужно вывести работодателей (inn), которые сменили ИНН, т.е. вывести старый и новый inn.

Одна организация может быть поглощена другой. При этом ИНН поглощаемой компании меняется (за один период) на ИНН поглотившей компании. Определить ИНН поглощенных компаний, и компаний, поглотивших их. Т.е. в данной выгрузке нужно найти изменения, которые произошли в январе по сравнению с декабрем.

Существует правило - компания, считается сменившей ИНН, если не менее чем у 90% сотрудников в компании в следующем месяце сменится ИНН, при этом по прежнему ИНН в следующем отчетном периоде не будет ни одного сотрудника.

Answer (score 0):

За основу можно взять что нибудь такое:

```
with inn_in_period as(
    select report_date, inn, count(1) all_client
      from data
     group by report_date, inn
),
lost_comp as(
    select d_old.*
      from inn_in_period d_old
      left join inn_in_period d_new
        on d_new.report_date=dateadd(month, 1, d_old.report_date)
       and d_new.inn=d_old.inn
     where d_new.inn is null
)
select l.report_date, d.inn as old_inn, n.inn as new_inn,
       count(1) cnt, l.all_client*0.9 need_cnt
  from lost_comp l, data d, data n
 where d.report_date=l.report_date and d.inn=l.inn
   and n.report_date=dateadd(month, 1, d.report_date)
   and n.client_id=d.client_id
 group by l.report_date, l.all_client, d.inn, n.inn
having count(1)>=l.all_client*0.9
```

Получаем списки ИНН по периодам с количеством сотрудников (all_client) в них. Назовем эту выборку `inn_in_period`.

Далее получаем те ИНН которые были в одном периоде и отсутствуют через месяц (`lost_comp`).

В итоговом запросе берем всех сотрудников исчезнувших ИНН и смотрим где они оказались в следующем месяце. Группируем до ИНН и получаем перешедших в этом направлении. Сверяем количество перешедших в группе с количеством сотрудников "пропавшего" ИНН.